# Is the mac cocoa development toolset considered rapid app development?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I heard someone say that developing on the mac using cocoa is great for rapid development.

Is it a good framework for building GUI based apps relatively fast?

Answer (score 1):

Here's for some historical perspective:

The Cocoa framework evolved from the NeXTSTEP framework when Apple bought NeXT (and Steve Jobs along with it) to form the basis of OS X. This is why you see lots of `NS` littered throughout Cocoa. And NeXTSTEP was one of the earliest frameworks to call itself a RAD framework. So from that point yes, Cocoa is a RAD framework.

There was a famous demo of how fast you can develop apps in NeXTSTEP where a full-fledged text editor (with font selection, file load/save, everything) was developed during the course of the demo (I believe it was under 30 minutes).

Another famous use of NeXTSTEP was the invention of the World Wide Web. Basically HTTP and HTML. Legend has it that Tim Berners-Lee cooked up HTTP and HTML and prototyped the worlds first web browser and web server in just a couple of days. And remember, that first web browser had the ability to edit as well as view HTML -- yes, the original internet was a giant Wiki!

Even at the time it was released as Cocoa around 96/97 it was still considered one of the top RAD environments around. This was around the time Borland was heavily positioning Delphi as a RAD environment and Microsoft's MFC was painful to use in comparison.

These days I would say that it is roughly comparable to .Net. Though I personally feel (and I know lots of long-time Cocoa programmers tend to share this sentiment) that Cocoa still has an edge in how fast I can take an idea to completion and how clean the resulting code is. It's an older framework, more mature and implemented lots of things right but other frameworks have had lots of time to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe the combination of Interface Builder and Cocoa makes prototyping an application faster than anything else I've used. Typically, creating something that is 'visible' takes just a few minutes using IB to wire controls to code, and a few more to write the code itself. Factor in the modular nature of View Controllers and the process of adding GUI elements to a large codebase is suddenly very easy. The next version of Xcode makes this process even faster, so I daresay you've got a lot to look forward to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the tools and willing to work with the provided UI elements then I think so. However because you're working with a fairly rich and stateful UI once you decide that you need custom views then you have signed up for some real work.

Overall I find web development slightly faster, largely because there's a wider selection of available libraries and frameworks to build on, but that's only an alternative for certain types of applications.